# Ultra bright points of light randomly appearing

Tags: compositing-nodes, ocean-simulation

I've been trying to create a stormy ocean with lightning, but there are a few random superbright pixels that blow up when I enable fog glow. I've tried turning the threshold to 1000, and they still appear. These are all in front of the "ocean" but in previous renders I had 1 point of light in the sky as well. Denoising is off. I tried turning off the mist pass. What could possibly be causing this?

Blend file(Waited 30 mins for giantcow to process the file, and it hasn't moved at all so Gdrive it is): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COR2JfXNYdBZ_g6ufzyd8fvssPJxknWB/view?usp=sharing

With fog glow:
[image: with fog glow enabled]

Without fog glow:
[image]

Compositor Nodes:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to be very bright specular highlights on the waves :

[image]

The fact that "Point.001" has a power of 3MW (!) is of course in cause ; but I guess you won't get the same dramatic effect if you lower that value.

What you can do is render the waves and the lightning in two distinct View Layers (formerly "Render Layers"), apply the fog glow only to the lightning layer, then merge the two layers with a Mix or AlphaOver node.

Comment: The thing is the ocean is partially in front and behind the lightning, so i'd have to separate it as well if I were to do it with layers?  Also earlier I had the lights on 5000W and the bright dots were there as well

Comment: 5000W is quite high too, but after all it's a lightning... To mask the parts of the lightning which are hidden by the ocean, You can set the ocean to "Holdout" in the lightning layer (in the Outliner ; must be in a separate collection). Sorry I can't help much with Layers in 2.8+.

Comment: If you're not confident with Layers, you can also use an Object Index or Material Index to isolate the lightning. That may be easier.

Comment: The holdout feature did the trick. Thanks!